# is available onClicklistener for Blackberry Map Location

Tags: blackberry, java-me, maps

I am displaying multiple locations in blackberry using following code

```
String document="<location-document><location lon='-8030000' lat='4326000' label='Kitchener, ON' description='Kitchener, Ontario, Canada' /><location lon='-7569792' lat='4542349' label='Ottawa, ON' description='Ottawa, Ontario, Canada' /></location-document>";
     MapsArguments map=new MapsArguments(
             MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,document);
     Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS,
                   map);
```

It works fine.But i have to switch to another screen which displays location address when the user clicks particular location.Is it possible by using above code.If it is not possible how can do that.Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: I'm very interested in this question, good luck from one BB dev. to another :). The only resource I could find that might be assistance was [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/3803/GPS%20and%20BlackBerry%20Maps%20Development%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to capture anything with that method.  The problem is that when you call `Invoke.invokeApplication` you are actually telling the BB to launch and pass control to the BB Maps application.  At this point, as far as I am aware, your app goes into the background and can not get any info from the BB Maps application.  If you want to have control over the map, you should look into the [MapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html) and/or [RichMapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/RichMapField.html).